# java hibernate save method on duplicate object reflect in original object

Tags: java, hibernate

Am making a copy of my original object `claim` to `copyClaim` using `BeanUtils.copyProperties` as below code.

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(claim, copyClaim);
```

But, when i tried to save only `copyClaim` object it reflects in original object also.

for example: In claim object am having the following fields with values

```
DealerNetPrice : 10.00
Descripton  : "ABC"
TotalCreditPaid : 20.00
TotalCreditPaidInUSD : 25.00
TotalCreditRequested : 22.00
```

After i used save method on `copyClaim` object, it reflects in `claim` object too like below.(which should not happen)

```
DealerNetPrice : null
Descripton  : null
TotalCreditPaid : null
TotalCreditPaidInUSD : null
TotalCreditRequested : null
```

Please find my below code which am trying.

```
@Override
public void updateClaimLineItemWithExtendedCreditPaidInDraft(Claim claim) {
    Claim copyClaim = new Claim();
    try {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(claim, copyClaim);
        for(ClaimLineItem cl : copyClaim.getClaimLineItems()) {
            cl.setDealerNetPrice(null);
            cl.setDescription(null);
        }
        copyClaim.setTotalCreditPaid(null);
        copyClaim.setTotalCreditPaidInUSD(null);
        copyClaim.setTotalCreditRequested(null);
        claimRepository.save(copyClaim);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        {
          ....
          ....
        }
}
```

Claim.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "claim")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(NON_EMPTY)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"ClaimNumber"}, callSuper = false)
@ToString(exclude = "parentClaim")
@ValidUpload
@ValidSpecificDebit
@CheckMarineDealer
@ValidClaimLineItems(groups = Submit.class)
public class Claim extends AuditableEntity implements Identifiable<Long>, AssignableEntity {


 ...
 ...

}
```

`Claim.java` is a very big method and `updateClaimLineItemWithExtendedCreditPaidInDraft` method is part of `Claim.java` class

Comment: That´s probably because you copy the id of the entity too. Try to exclude it in the copyProperties method

Comment: @C.Weber can you tell me how to exclude id alone.?

Comment: Just add the properties that shouldn´t be copied as additional parameters. BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target, "propertyName", "additionalpropertyName");

Answer (score 0):

Using BeanUtils.copyProperties or clone on a database entity with hibernate annotations to create another database entity is dangerous.

You probably also copied the primary key field. The new object isn't managed by hibernate but when saving it, hibernate sees the primary key value and finds the original one with the same primary key value and merges the new data in the original object which it is already managing.

The save method will probably also return the original object, which basically means hibernate assumes you won't use the new object anymore after it was merged but you should use the returned object instead, which is managed by hibernate.